# Remove blank lines from text file c#

Tags: c#, text

Im trying to read a  text file using `File.ReadAllText`, break it into single words and remove those unders certain length. But the thing is that blank lines or paragraphs are also count in a word length. 
Text example:

> Just some simple text.
>
> Here and there.

If we were to count words length it would look like this:

> [Blockquote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz2L6.png)

As you can see length of text. and Here became 13.

Here`s the code

```
var allLines =
            File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Default)
                .Split(' ')
                .Where(c => c.Length > wordLength)
                .Select(word => word);
        var newLine = string.Join(" ", allLines);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to include carriage returns '\r' and line feeds '\n' in your Split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the comment from SpaceghostAli, and the answer from Theofanis Pantelides:

```
        var allLines =
            File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Default)
            .Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(c => c.Length > wordLength);
```

Comment: Thanks, completely missed it

Answer (score 3):

Not very legible but you could String.Split with StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries:

```
String allLines = string.Join(" ", File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Default)
                  .Split(new string[] { " ", "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```